# why is 3 not prime number?

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

Function to identify is n [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) or not.

```
def test_prime(n):
  
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n==2:
        return True
    else:
        for e in range(2,n): # iteration from 2 to n
            if e % 2 == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

Why is 3 not prime number here?

```
  print(test_prime(3))
```

Comment: Did you mean: `if n % e == 0:`?

Comment: I mean, imagine how easily we could find prime numbers if the only thing we had to check was whether a number was divisible by 2, as you do in `if e % 2 == 0:`. Your code ends up finding even or odd numbers

Comment: Yes , you're right that would be much easier. I just wonder why only number 3 returns **False'**  in this code when **3** includes only 2 without 3.

Comment: Because the logic is incorrect.

Comment: @MasterMind Because you loop e from 2 to n-1. You then check `e % 2` or... `2 % 2` which is equal to 0, so false. This'll happen for _every_ number (except 1 and 2 with their special cases).

Comment: And you need not loop till `n-1` , only till `n/2`

Comment: @NIck , now I understand 2%2 = 0 which is False.  Thanks Nick.

Comment: @Kris Not even n/2. The square root of n is enough.

Comment: How can I improve my question so its not -3........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the logic you have implemented is wrong. As it is already pointed out, your code currently is checking whether or not your input number is even or odd. For checking if the number is prime, you can do as follows:

```python
def test_prime(n):
  
    if n == 1:
        return False
    elif n==2:
        return True
    else:
        for e in range(2,n): # iteration from 2 to n
            if n % e == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

The `else` condition will check whether the remainder after dividing the input number by each number in `range` is 0 or not. If it's 0 then it's not a prime number. Also, you could run the loop from 0 to half of `n`, which is more efficient as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 is not prime number because of the logic in the code which goes from range(2,n), what will return number 2 and 2%2 == 0 which is False.